# Turn based game, which drawing method?

Tags: android, drawing, 2d

I am going to create a simple turn based 2D game for Android and as far as I know there are basically three methods to do the drawing.

- Using a "normal" View, and only drawing when needed (for example on a touch event).
- Using a SurfaceView combined with a "game loop" in a separate thread, drawing on each loop iteration.
- OpenGL (I have no idea how this works yet).

When I made a small simulation game (a la Farmville) I used the SurfaceView, because it used some simple animation, and if I used a "normal" View, I had to use a Timer to update the graphics at certain intervals. I don't know which one of the two methods was better, but the SurfaceView method seemed to be easier. On the other hand, I figure that using an infinite "game loop" drains the battery very quickly. As for OpenGL, I have no idea how that works or if it is way too complicated for simple games.

So if I have a simple turn based game (think a bit like the fighting parts of Pokémon), which of the above methods would be best? What do other games use (like Angry Birds, DanteInferno, Inotia, Jewels, Robo Defense, Wisp, Zonina, etc)?

I find that the information on the web is very unclear on which to use when.

Comment: There is a dedicated community for this kind of questions: gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Den, sorry I had no clue... it's been a while since I have been on Stack Overflow, so I didn't realise there was a separate community for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a simple board game which is kind of a turned based game and i used SurfaceView and it came out pretty darn good. You can optimize SurfaceView, but You'll eventually run into problems if you use standard views, specially if you have a scrolling game.

I've use this article and it was very helpful, it has a bunch of different methods of implementing the game loop with their pros and cons:  http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ 
It's a good starting point.

About the draining of the battery - you can use Thread.sleep() so it will last longer. Didn't do any tests on the battery yet, but you have to face the fact that games drain battery, specially if you play it for hours :)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'll have a look at that link and see what I can gather. What do you mean with a scrolling game, exactly? And how does that influence the choice? I know that games drain battery anyway, but I think a small game (think Bejeweled-type) should not drain as much battery as a very complicated, big game (think Angry Birds or even Doom/Quake, which have been ported to phones already).

Comment: Scrolling game: When you have a game where the level is wider/higher than the screen size, you have to scroll around. In angry birds when u swipe left/right zoomin/zoomou. It's better to do this using SurfaceView beacause u can optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL also uses a drawing loop which is called repeatedly, so it will operate in a similar fashion to your SurfaceView approach. OpenGL is praised for its performance capabilities but does carry with it quite a lot of complexity - for a small project it might not be worth the investment, unless you fancy learning about how it works!

As for battery life, the most CPU intensive tasks will be the most draining, meaning the redrawing strategy (time based or event-driven) which is most effecient will be the best choice. Benchmarking a simple prototype should give you an idea of which works best with your game code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done game development on Android but I have been creating an application that involves a lot of animated and scrolling UI elements. For this project I've used a mixture of normal extended Views and SurfaceViews, and I've had to borrow lots of techniques traditionally used in game programming. Along the way I've learned how normal Views and SurfaceViews differ, and the pros and cons of using each.

The big difference between the two, which I think is important to grasp, is that with a SurfaceView you're in effect almost directly writing to the screen buffer (not technically correct - but the easiest way to think about it) as soon as you want, and often as you'd like (within limits). It doesn't 'sit' within the normal View hierarchy. Being able to draw in this manner allows for fast animated graphics (particularly by offsetting bitmaps to create scrolling backgrounds and overlaying animated bitmap sprites over the top). Your code does the drawing directly when it wants to. Main disadvantage of a SurfaceView as far as I have been able to tell from my own experience is that you cannot have any other View appear behind it (i.e. no transparency effects).

A normal View on the other hand sits in the normal View hierarchy. Unlike with a SurfaceView you *cannot* perform a redraw of a normal View as soon as your code wants to. You have to call `invalidate()` (or `postInvalidate()` from a non-UI thread) on that View to tell the system that you want to redraw it, and then the system will eventually call that View's `onDraw()` after some time to do the drawing. There's no guarantee on how quickly that'll be called and this potentially limits the speed at which you can update graphics. The advantage of a normal View however is that it sits within the normal View heirarchy and you can have Views placed on top of each other with transparency and so on.